# SQLAlchemy Invalid Foreign Key with PostgreSQL but not SQLite

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I can create the following tables in an SQLite database:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Paragraph(db.Model):
    article_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('article.id'), primary_key=True)
    index = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Summary(db.Model):
    article_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('article.id'), primary_key=True)
    paragraph_index = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('paragraph.index'), primary_key=True)
    level = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

However, when I create the same tables in PostgreSQL, I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "paragraph"

Removing `Summary.paragraph_index` allows me to create the tables, so it appears that the issue lies here. However, the column *does* reference a primary key, which I feel should satisfy the requirement.

Adding `unique=True` to `Paragraph.index` also allows me to create the tables. I can then remove the unique constraint using pgAdmin and have everything work fine. However, this seems improper.

I have also tried:

- declaring the relationship via the ORM
- declaring ForeignKeyConstraint in Summary table args
- declaring UniqueConstraint in Paragraph table args for the primary key columns

Comment: Unless you set `PRAGMA foreign_keys` from here [Pragmas](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) on  your SQLite database FK's will be ignored. This is why you did not get error for SQLite. Also `primary_key=True` for `paragraph_index` is not going to work as `paragraph_index` can be repeated as the child in the FK parent-child relationship. Same for `article_id`. Same for `article_id` in `Paragraph`. You need to rethink what you are trying to achieve. Would also be a good idea to read up on FKs.

Comment: You should also take a look at [Relationships](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/).

Comment: As I understand from the [ORM configuration docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html), setting multiple primary keys would create a composite PK. This is also stated in the docs that you linked as "Multiple keys can be marked as primary keys in which case they become a compound primary key." It is my intention to make the combination of columns unique rather than the individual columns themselves.

Comment: The error you are getting is about the the FK not the PK. In the Postgres client `psql` do `\d paragraph`. I'm betting you will see a PK that is `(article_id, index)` . In the model  `Summary` your FK `paragraph_index` is pointing at only half that PK, hence the error.

Comment: You're right, that *is* what I see. According to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html), 'the `ForeignKeyConstraint` is the only way to define a composite foreign key. Unfortunately, this is a table level constraint which requires that I remove the `ForeignKey` definition on the individual columns; I lose my bidirectional relationship from `Article` to `Summary`. Thank you for your advice. I will rethink my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the comments by [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver), of which I am grateful, I have used `__table_args__` to point `Summary` at both halves of the composite primary key on `Paragraph`:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Paragraph(db.Model):
    article_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('article.id'), primary_key=True)
    index = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Summary(db.Model):
    article_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('article.id'), primary_key=True)
    paragraph_index = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    level = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
        ['article_id', 'paragraph_index'],
        ['paragraph.article_id', 'paragraph.index']),)
```